# Need explaination on C function and its return type

Tags: c

I am trying to understand how to interface with a function inside of a DLL for my 40MHZ SPI transceiver.  Particularly I am not sure I understand how the function is defined and what inputs it is taking.  I am a beginner in C, so your expertise would really help me a lot.

Below is piece of the C driver code I am trying to understand.   I am under the assumption that the function takes buffer pointers and somehow fills the buffer with data once I call the 'c_ch_find_devices_ext' function, but I am confuse by the return type because in the API document, the return type is an int, but in here it seems to be returning the function itself???

```
static int (*c_ch_find_devices_ext) (int, u16 *, int, u32 *) = 0;
int ch_find_devices_ext (
 int   num_devices,
 u16 * devices,
 int   num_ids,
 u32 * unique_ids
)
{
    if (c_ch_find_devices_ext == 0) {
        int res = 0;
        if (!(c_ch_find_devices_ext = _loadFunction("c_ch_find_devices_ext", &res)))
            return res;
    }
    return c_ch_find_devices_ext(num_devices, devices, num_ids, unique_ids);
}
```

Below is the API documentation on the  'c_ch_find_devices_ext', is it accurate???

```
Find Devices (ch_find_devices_ext)
  int ch_find_devices_ext (int   num_devices,
                           u16 * devices,
                           int   num_ids,
                           u32 * unique_ids);

Get a list of ports and unique IDs to which Cheetah devices are attached.

Arguments
    num_devices: maximum number of devices to return 
    devices: array into which the port numbers are returned
    num_ids: maximum number of device IDs to return
    unique_ids: array into which the unique IDs are returned

Return Value
    This function returns the number of devices found, regardless of the array size.
```

Comment: it's not returning the function. That would look like `return c_ch_find_devices_ext`. Google "function call".

Comment: In C calling function by pointer looks the same as usual calling by "name". I.e. `c_ch_find_devices_ext(num_devices, devices, num_ids, unique_ids)` is simply a shortcut for `(*c_ch_find_devices_ext)(num_devices, devices, num_ids, unique_ids)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially answerable by reading a beginners' language tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The return type is int. What you probably find confusing is, that, the C function is not the method itself, but rather a pointer to a function, which is obtained at a later time.

```
 static int (*c_ch_find_devices_ext) (int, u16 *, int, u32 *) = 0;
```

This defines `c_ch_find_devices_ext` as a pointer to a function which returns `int` and has the specified arguments.

If the pointer was not initialized i.e = NULL then the pointer is loaded from some shared library (my assumption), or some other method which is what `_loadFunction` does.

```
if (c_ch_find_devices_ext == 0) {
    int res = 0;
    if (!(c_ch_find_devices_ext = _loadFunction("c_ch_find_devices_ext", &res)))
        return res;
}
```

Use the pointer to the function, just like it were the function itself returning an int (as documented).

```
return c_ch_find_devices_ext(num_devices, devices, num_ids, unique_ids);
```

Comment: I thoroughly enjoyed your explanation, thank you much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple `int` return type and yes, the documentation is correct for this function. It returns the number of devices found.

What confused you probably is that the function is in fact a pointer to a function.